# Variable scope in callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I ran into a problem with my javascript code.

I have a class `MyClass` and added function `myFunction` to its prototype.

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(file){
    if(some condition){
       fs.exists("./" + file, function(exists){
           if(exists)
               console.log(this.someValue);
               /* lot of other code */
           else
               /* do something else */
    });
    }else{
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

My problem is the scoping of `this.someValue`(as an example I want to just print it).
Everytime `exists` equals `true` the console logs `undefined` but it is not.
If I would print it outside of `fs.exists()` then it has a value so I guess it is a scoping problem.

How can I access `this.someValue` in this sample?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `this` - is keyword that is defined by scope of function and responds to owner or caller of a function. So you might store its pointer in another variable:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(file) {
  if(some condition) {
    var self = this; // create variable with pointer to 'this'
    fs.exists("./" + file, function(exists) {
      if(exists) {
        console.log(self.someValue); // we can access it to parent scope variables
        /* lot of other code */
      } else {
        /* do something else */
      }
    });
  } else {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

As well check out this brilliant topic: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: `{ location: London"` is invalid, fwiw

Comment: Typo.. Thanks for spotting out.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `.bind` your inner function

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(file){
    if(some condition){
       fs.exists("./" + file, function(exists){
           if(exists)
               console.log(this.someValue);
               /* lot of other code */
           else
               /* do something else */
    }.bind(this));
    }else{
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

This can be rewritten to be cleaner

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function myFunction(file){
  if(some condition){
    fs.exists("./" + file, this.doSomething.bind(this));
  }
  else{
    // do something else
  }
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething(exists) {
  if(exists) {
    console.log(this.someValue);
    // lot of other code
  }
  else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

I personally like this solution because it allows you to maintain excellent code composition and prevents you from nesting `function(){ function(){ function(){ ... }}}`. It also prevents you from having a bunch of `var that = this;` or `var self = this;` variables floating around having you wonder which scope is which.

`.bind` is slower, yes, but as minitech points out, it's certainly not going to be your bottleneck when compared to file access.

Comment: Binding is one of the slowest ways of passing scope pointer into another function. And has slightly different application purpose.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs: Slow relative to file access? Don’t micro-optimize…

Comment: Not relative to file operation, but slow for such simple operation. In fact it is dramatic difference, please check out here: http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-setup/6

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs the original question, and this answer, both use it in the context of a `fs.exists()` callback. If it was in the middle of a tight loop, I'd agree with you, but when it's mixed in with file I/O the performance penalty background noise at worst, and `.bind()` does result in more easily understandable code (`this` all the way down).

Comment: i like your solution too. in fact it is much more readable for this use case :) I'll test it too but I think it is not that nice for bigger functions because of scrolling :)

Comment: @deoxxa generally using .bind without real need - is not good style. That why I went a bit against it. Relative to performance - it is all fine and your points make obvious sense. But it is just not a good style to do so, especially if you are developing multi-team stuff and there is many places where function is executed from - can lead to big confusion generally.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs can you define "good style"? Or explain how `var self = this;` is less confusing?

Comment: @deoxxa please read this great post: http://pmuellr.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/bind-considered-harmful.html
`.bind` has rare but real need, but that is really rare and very specific cases. Generally check link above it nearly covers everything related to bind.

Answer (score 3):

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function(file){
  var that = this;
  // some lines of code later...
       console.log(that.someValue);
}
```